# How to store multiple scope objects in a single scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 scope objects.

```
$scope.aaa;
$scope.bbb;
```

I want to pass it as list to backend.so I tried to store in single object.

```
$scope.fullData={$scope.aaa,$scope.bbb}
```

I tried to console `$scope.fullData`.Its showing some red color error line in `dot` of both objects.

How can I send it as single object/array/list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add property names to make it a valid object.

```
$scope.fullData = {
  aaa: $scope.aaa,
  bbb: $scope.bbb
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change the curly brackets to square brackets if you want to send an array

```
$scope.fullData=[$scope.aaa,$scope.bbb]
```